# Oracle JDK 7 not installed and E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu-14.04

[Oracle JDK7 not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlVNX.png)

Iam have created a new container in server and trying to install JDK7 in that container. It failed installing oracle JDK 7. Even i tried changing the version like JDK 8 and 9 but still it respond that JDK 7 not installed.
Please help me how to install Oracle JDK in server.

Answer (score 1):

1)    `sudo apt-get update`

2)    `java -version` when returned The program java can be found in the following packages

2.1) `sudo apt-get install default-jre`

2.3) `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

3)`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

3.1)`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

4) insatll oracle jdk

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

5) `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

Comment: Thank you soo much. It helped me.